Multi line chat messages are now limited to 10k characters?
Since the beginning of chat, multi line chat messages enjoyed the freedom of not having limit, or more accurate, they could reach around 2 million (!) characters.
However, as of few days ago, I noticed this is no longer the case, and it's now limited to 10k characters.
Is this intentional, and if so, what is the reasoning behind it, and why wasn't it limited before?

There was a limit, it was just not correctly enforced because of a bug. I fixed that bug last week, and also did two other things:

reduce that limit to 10k (the not-actually-enforced limit was 100k which feels really excessive)
make the client aware of that limit, so you get the "this message is too long" complaint immediately, instead of after you try to post


How many messages are currently out there on each server which are over the limit? This  would create a problem should a moderator wish to edit one of those messages.

In a similar vein, why not bump the limit for single-line messages to 600 characters, to match the comment length limit? Currently, mods cannot edit messages that were created from comments above 500 characters being moved to chat.

@Sonic regarding the "match the comment length limit", it's totally worth a new feature request, I looked for one now and was surprised there isn't any, or I couldn't find it.

OK. Thank you for informing us. I will disable the SmokeDetector features which required > 10k characters per multi-line chat message.

@Makyen I'm happy to accommodate Smoky -- what kind of limit would work? What kinds of messages are those?
